# Runtime polymorphism decision

Tags: java, jvm, polymorphism, compiler-optimization

I have read somewhere that runtime polymorphism is a result of dynamic typing in langugages. By inspecting the code below we can see a clear example of runtime polymorphism.

```
class A{
    do(){}
}
class B extends A{
    do(){}
}
...
A ex = new B();
ex.do();
```

Since there is superclass type reference , compiler can't decide which type will reference refer actually and binds method in the runtime.but what about the usage below with same class definitions?

My 1st question is for the example below;

```
class A{
    do(){}
}
class B extends A{
  //no overriding
}
...
A ex = new B();
ex.do();
```

There is only one version of method do() in the hierarchy. Does the system still wait runtime to bind the method?Or does it bind in compile time?

My second question is for the example below;

```
class A{
    do(){}
}
class B extends A{
  do(){}
}
...
B ex = new B();
ex.do();
```

There is subclass(lowest in inheritance chain) type reference now. Will it be bound in runtime?

Comment: It is hard to determine at compile time how many implementations are available because somebody can add it's own implementation at run time. But at runtime JIT can speculate about hierarchy and do the following things http://stackoverflow.com/a/33351238/1352098

Answer (score 5):

When compiling a invocation of a non-static method `javac` will always use a `invokevirtual` instruction, so there is no optimization done at compile time.

But since devirtualization of method calls is an important optimization (save the vtable lookup, possibly inline the method) the runtime (hotspot, etc.) will *try* to apply it if possible due to code analysis.

So in your second example (third code block) the runtime *might* recognize that it can replace the virtual call to `A.do` with a call to `B.do` since `ex` *is* actually a `B` (should be trivial to figure out by the runtime in this case).

For your first example (second code block) there is another optimization technique. The runtime first sees class `A`. Any invocations of `A.do` are now compiled as static invocations as if no derived class exists which overrides `A.do`. If such a class is later loaded the runtime will rollback this optimistic assumption and introduce virtual method calls instead.

Comment: Any insights on the third example?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom clarified the refs: "second example" = third code block in the question

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the term “dynamic typing”, the way it is used in your question, is misleading at best. Java is *not* a “dynamically-typed programming language”. It offers certain dynamic type-checks, like type casts and the `instanceof` operator, but in your code example, no dynamic type check is involved. It’s all statically typed.

By the way, `do` is not a legal method name in Java. But assuming, `A` declares a method `doSomething` and there is a subclass `B`, then it is completely irrelevant to the Java compiler whether `B` overrides `doSomething` or not (unless it changes the access modifiers).

The point is, `A` and `B` are distinct classes and can get (re-)compiled independently and there is no guaranty that `B` still does (not) override that method at runtime. But the specification considers such kind of change to be within the legal range that should not break the binary compatibility:

> #### [13.4.24. Method Overriding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.24)
>
> If an instance method is added to a subclass and it overrides a method in a superclass, then the subclass method will be found by method invocations in pre-existing binaries, and these binaries are not impacted.
>
> If a class method is added to a class, then this method will not be found unless the qualifying type of the reference is the subclass type.

Note the last sentence regarding “class methods”, aka `static` methods. It implies that when `A` declares a `static` method `m` and you invoke it via `B.m`, the invocation may end up in a `static` method declared by `B` if `B` happens to declare such method at runtime, even if the version seen at compile time didn’t. So even the early-bound, non-polymorphic methods are eventually resolved at runtime and may find a different target than found at compile-time. The difference to late-bound methods is that, once the early-bound methods are resolved, the invocation is always dispatched to the method, not depending on any property that could change at runtime.

For the overridable methods, the method is resolved according to the compile-time type of the reference on which is it invoked and *then* there might be an overriding method in the actual runtime type of the reference. This is the place to forwardly answer a potential follow-up question:

> #### [13.4.17. final Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.17)
>
> Changing a method that is declared `final` to no longer be declared `final` does not break compatibility with pre-existing binaries.

In other words, when you are invoking a method which is `final` at compile-time, the compiler will take no advantage of the fact that the target method is `final` as it is possible that the method is not `final` at runtime and this possibility must not break compatibility.

The only method invocation which gets special treatment, is the invocation of `private` methods. Since the invoker of a `private` method is always within the same class as the method declaration itself, they are always compiled together and not subject to independent evolution.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. It is originated from Grady Booch's OOAD book.Below screenshot shows the source . Thanks for the heads up.
http://imgur.com/9iirXRj

Answer (score 0):

Whether the compiler binds at comile time or the JVM binds at runtime is deliberately left undefined. The java specification does will not state one way or another - it will only state that by the time the code is run the expected results will be achieved [Citation Needed].

Early/late binding is an optimisation and is therefore optional.